# How to implement the language automatically in detect sentiment in azure text analytics in a logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, sentiment-analysis, text-analytics-api

I've created a logic app which detects the language of a text and then the sentiment with cognitive services. I want to change the language parameter to the actual language which is detected. I've tried the following and much other stuff but it doesn't work out for me.[image]
Can anyone suggest me a solution?
(The text is German but when I run it it says: "Supplied language not supported. Pass in one of: ar,da,de,el,en,es,fi,fr,it,ja,nl,no,pl,pt-PT,ru,sv,tr,zh-Hans")
For a copy:

> Hallo E-Bike Team, ich habe ein Problem mit meinem E-Bike. Es ist das
> Model ProRide2E. Seit heute Morgen steht auf dem Display folgender
> Hinweis: „Akkuleistung beeinträchtigt. Fehlercode: XB1200AB“ Das darf
> doch wohl nicht wahr sein. Ich bin echt sauer. Wieso ist das doofe
> Bike immer kaputt?
>
> Ein genervter Kunde
>
> Name

Comment: Wrong screenshot, sorry! The language parameter should be item@('Detect_Language')?['iso6391Name'] not item@('Detect_Sentiment')?['iso6391Name']! But with language it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added dynamic content instead of the @('Detect_Language')?['iso6391Name']. The dynamic content was Language Code. That created a for each loop. In the response I didnt output score as usual I added a expression (body('Detect_Sentiment')[0]?['score']) That worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Great that you resolved this. Now, concerning the Iso-6391 names, both detecting language and translating text relies on string values and sadly Azure AI don't have any enums to have some type safety. But I guess the list of supported languages grows ever more then..

I made a list of the Iso6391 names of supported languages in Azure here. As you can see, German language is 'de' for example :

https://github.com/toreaurstadboss/MultiLingual.Translator/blob/main/MultiLingual.Translator.Lib/Models/LanguageCode.cs

The repo is a runnable MAUI Blazor app that can detect language and translate text into the desired language of the cirka 130 languages supported in Azure Cognitive Services Translator Services.